# Extremal values of a family of cubic polynomials

Tags: calculus, functions

I'm having trouble solving this.

Investigate the extreme values of the function f, defined by $f(x) = x^3 + 3px + q$, for all $x ∈ R$, $p, q$ being fixed real numbers.

Comment: How you would investigate extreme values of, say, $f(x)=x^2+4x+3$? What is the difference here, from your point of view?

Comment: Have you tried something? Do you know what the general approach is to finding the extreme values of _any_ function?

Comment: Please show some effort.

Comment: I've tried finding f'(x), but the p and the q are somehow stopping me from solving this...I know you have to solve f'(x) = 0 and after that find f''(x), so that you can find the minima and maxima (sorry if it's hard to understand me, but i'm studying functions in german and it's kind of hard..)

Comment: What is your f'(x)? Hint: It is allowed to have a $p$ or $q$ in it, though the $q$ will not appear.

Comment: Well my f'(x) is 3x^2 +3p .... so that means that 3x^2 + 3p = 0, which is 3x^2 = -3p, but then x^2 = -p ...or i'm doing something wrong?

Comment: You are in the right track: $x^2=-p$ is not a difficult equation to solve, remember $p$ is a real number.

Comment: so does that mean that x can be sqrt(-p)?

Comment: Well, probably $p$ has to be $\leq 0$, and we have two roots.